# Create a under column to column

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sqlite

How to add an undercolumn to a column? Example:

```
class CreateMessages < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :messages do |t|
        t.text :text
      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

I want to add another column for every new text column. I think I have to use the text column's id, but i'm not sure. How should I do it?

Comment: Sounds like you need a join table. Need more info.

Comment: I'm trying to create a blog with a commenting feature. For every post that i create (to the :text column), there have to be another column that stores the comments.

Comment: One column for multiple comments? Doesn't sound like a good idea. Should be a separate table instead.

Comment: you probably don't want to store the comments in 1 text field with the actual post? You probably want to create a comments table, with a comment fields that references messages.id ?

Comment: Thanks, I will try that!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per the comments, you'll be best using another model to achieve this:

```
#app/models/message.rb
class Message < ActiveRecord::Base
   has_many :comments
end

#app/models/comment.rb
class Comment < ActiveRecord::Base
   belongs_to :message
end
```

This will allow you to create a number of `comments` for any `message` that is created. This is known as a [`has_many` / `belongs_to` relationship](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has-many-association):

[image]